# Dynamically create Mysql query based on number of elements in list in Python

Tags: python, mysql, list, sql-like, mysql-python

I have a list of items:

```
list1 = ['abc', 'cde']
```

So, the number of elements in the list can change based on input to the function.
I want to generate a query like this from the list:

```
SELECT  *
FROM   table
WHERE   column LIKE '%abc%' AND column LIKE '%cde%' and length(column)<=7
```

So this query needs to be generated dynamically based on elements in the list. Because the number of LIKE commands will increase with number of elements in the list, I am unable to get it in place. The length`(column)<=7` part is also dynamic but I can configure that as it is static. Can anyone help me generate the query with multiple LIKE commands based on number of list elements

Comment: use string ```format``` and a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this with python so I'm assuming you can use that.

```
command = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE'
list1 = ['abc', 'cde', 'efg']

for i in list1:
    condition = " column LIKE '%" + i + "%' AND"
    command += condition

command += " length(column)<=7"

print(command)
```

this returns

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%abc%' AND column LIKE '%cde%' AND column LIKE '%efg%' AND length(column)<=7
```

Comment: Thanks. So column name needs to be repeated else the query will fail. So if I make it `condition = " LIKE '%" + i + "'% AND column"` the query becomes `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%abc'% AND column LIKE '%cde'% AND column LIKE '%efg'% AND column length(column)<=7` but it needs to be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%abc'% AND column LIKE '%cde'% AND column LIKE '%efg'% AND length(column)<=7`. Can you please check

Comment: That looks like invalid SQL to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can format `list1` as a `cte` and then use `all` with a subquery:

```
list1 = ['abc', 'cde']
query = """
  with vals(column) as (
     {}
  )
  select t1.* from table t1 where 1 = all 
    (select t1.column like concat('%', v1.column, '%') from vals v1) and length(t1.column) <= 7;
""".format('\nunion all\n'.join(f'select "{i}"' for i in list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list1 = ['abc', 'cde']
col_length = 7
def generate_sql_query(where_clause, col_length):
    
    return """SELECT  *
    FROM   table
    WHERE  {0}
    AND length(column)<={1}
    """.format(where_clause, col_length)
def where_clause(wherelist, column):
    res = ' 1=1 \n'
    for elem in wherelist:
        temp = "AND " + column + " LIKE '%" + elem + "%'\n"
        res += temp
    return res
res = generate_sql_query(where_clause(list1, 'colname'), col_length)
print(res)
```

### Output

```py
SELECT  *
    FROM   table
    WHERE   1=1 
AND colname LIKE '%abc%'
AND colname LIKE '%cde%'

    AND length(column)<=7
```

Comment: thanks but this is fetching empty rows. Can you please check so that the query becomes in this format exactly:

`SELECT  *
FROM   table
WHERE   column LIKE '%abc%' AND column LIKE '%cde%' and length(column)<=7`

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing where the elements in `list1` came from (they could have been provided by a user), you might need to be concerned about SQL Injection attacks. Therefore, you should consider using a prepared statement:

```py
list1 = ['abc', 'def']
# The prepared statement:
sql = 'select * from table where ' + ' and '.join('column like %s' for _ in list1) + ' and length(column)<=7'
# The actual arguments to the prepared statement
args = ['%' + elem + '%' for elem in list1]
# And then something like:
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```